# Angular 4.2.4 HttpInterceptor not working when used in forRoot() of shared module

Tags: angular, module, lazy-loading

I am using a shared module to provide components and services to other lazy-loaded modules in my Angular 4.2.4 app.

Everything is working well except for my injected HttpInterceptor.

If I add it to the forRoot() of the shared module then it does not get injected for my HttpCLient calls in my lazy-loaded modules.

If I leave it in the regular providers: [] section of the shared module it does get injected into my lazy-loaded modules but then it is no longer treated as a singleton and gets initialized for each module.

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

For now I am just going to allow the interceptor to have multiple instances but it isn't what I want in the end.

**shared.module.ts** (does not work in lazy-loaded)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [ ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [ ]
})  
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        HttpClient,
         {
           provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
           useClass: JwtHttpInterceptor,
           multi: true
         }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

**shared.module.ts** (works in lazy-loaded but is not a singleton)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [ ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: JwtHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})  
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        HttpClient
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    ShellComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**admin.module.ts** (lazy-loaded module)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [ ],
  providers: [ ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the same problem with `sharedmodule` and `forRoot`

See:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20575

**Try removing `HttpClientModule` from your shared module**